# Sort a relationship in cosmicmind graph's library

Tags: ios, relationship, entity-relationship, swift3, cosmicmind

I'm using the graph library and I need sort a relationship from a relationship.subject field [ " idOrder " ] .
it's possible to do it?
And if IdOrder isn't a int but a date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do this for Swift 3, which is currently in the development branch.

```
_ = graph.search(forRelationship: ["T1"]).sorted { (a, b) -> Bool in
        return a.subject!["idOrder"] as! Int > b.subject!["idOrder"] as! Int
    }
```

All the best :)

Comment: I am very grateful for the answer. He helped me a lot. If instead of a whole it were a date?

Comment: For a date, you can use the `createdDate` property like so

graph.search(forRelationship: ["T1"]).sorted { (a, b) -> Bool in
return a.createdDate < b.createdDate
}